# Python parameterized query and insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ocr, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc connector for storing data and image into SQL Server. The storing function contains parameterized arguments which the value was supply by global variables from others function.

With hard-coded the values, I able to insert into the DB without any issue, but seems like no luck when trying to insert using the variable values.

What is the right method for me to execute this transaction in Python? Any help/advice is highly appreciated!

```
  def convertToBinaryData(filename):
  # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
      binaryData = file.read()
    return binaryData


  def saveRecord1(self,DocumentType, FileName, DocumentContent, DocumentText, LastUpdate, UpdatedBy):
    print("Inserting into database")

    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=localhost;'
                          'Database=testDB;'
                          'uid=test;'
                          'pwd=test01;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=No;')

    cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)

    sql_insert_blob_query = """INSERT INTO testDB.dbo.OCRDocuments (DocumentType, FileName, DocumentContent, DocumentText, LastUpdate, UpdatedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"""

    pics = convertToBinaryData(DocumentContent)

    insert_blob_tuple = (DocumentType, FileName, pics, DocumentText, LastUpdate, UpdatedBy)

    result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_blob_query, insert_blob_tuple)

    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Status', 'Successfully saved!',
                              QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel, QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

#saveRecord( 'k1', 'imgFileType', "output.png", '2020-10-27 11:20:47.000', '2020-10-27 11:20:47.000','1000273868')
 saveRecord1(self, docType, imgFileType, output, docNum, datetime,userID)
```

Comment: You do `pics = convertToBinaryData(DocumentContent)` but then you don't seem to use `pics`anywhere else.

Comment: @GordThompson I have made a correction to include the pics variable into query statement